# Spring Security does not recognice protected JSF page in some cases

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-security

I set up an JSF (SpringFaces) and Spring Security application where I protected the customer.jsf page in applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/customer**" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR,ROLE_TELLER" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/pages/login.jsf" default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.jsf" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout*" logout-success-url="/" />

</http>
```

On the main.jsf page I have a link to the customer.jsf. When I click this link, the customer page opens without security check! This is some log output:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /pages/main.jsf at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@10de3a. A new one will be created.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest - requestURI: arg1=/TestProject/pages/customer.jsf; arg2=/TestProject/pages/main.jsf (property not equals)
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/pages/main.jsf'; against '/pages/customer**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
```

But when I am on customer page already, and then clicking the link to customer page itself, I get the login page and following log output:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /pages/customer.jsf at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@10de3a. A new one will be created.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest - requestURL: arg1=http://localhost:8080/TestProject/pages/customer.jsf; arg2=http://localhost:8080/TestProject/pages/customer.jsf (property equals)
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/pages/customer.jsf'; against '/pages/customer**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterScurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /pages/customer.jsf; Attributes: [ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_TELLER]
```

Seems, the source page (from where i come) is security checked, but not the target page (where I want to go to).

This is some configuration in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

All other pages in the application are not protected and work fine.
Any hint what's wrong?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: I think in your link, you need a send-redirect to customer page, so that url changes and spring security be aware of that change